# angular library: automatically install @types/youtube along

Tags: angular, youtube-iframe-api, angular-library

I created an angular library (node package) that provides a youtube player.

The project containing the library also contains a test project that works as expected. The package for my library contains the peerDependency `@types/youtube`, which is needed for typescript autocompletion. To see the test project working:

```
git clone https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-youtube-player
cd mintplayer-ng-youtube-player
npm install
npm start -- --open
```

[image: The angular app in the same repository is working fine]

I now tried creating a new angular app to test the library.

```
ng new YoutubeTest --routing=false --style=scss
cd YoutubeTest
npm install --save @mintplayer/ng-youtube-player
```

Then you can [implement it in the project](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/AngularYoutubeTest)

app.module.ts (Add the YoutubePlayerModule)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { YoutubePlayerModule } from '@mintplayer/ng-youtube-player';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    YoutubePlayerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<youtube-player [domId]="'player1'" #player1></youtube-player>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'youtube-test';
  @ViewChild('player1') player1!: YoutubePlayerComponent;
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.player1.playVideoById('yFKhgF_vkgs');
  }
}
```

But when you run the project (`npm start -- --open`) you'll get errors in the console because `@types/youtube` is not installed. I already tried including `@types/youtube` as devDependency, the `@types/youtube` package is not installed after running `npm install` or even `npm install --dev`. This seems to have been an adaptation by npm in the past. I also tried as normal dependency, but then angular tells you that you'd have to explicitly allow this.

Can I include `@types/youtube` as a dependency (or better devDependency) in my library so that the consuming application developer does not have to install it manually? Or is it supposed to be like this?

```
npm install --save @example/ng-youtube-player
npm install --save-dev @types/youtube
```

Comment: Yes, you can include it as a `devDependency` in the library so the consumer does not have to install it. If you added `@types/youtube` to `devDependency` of your main project and then ran `npm install`, make sure you delete `package-lock.json` and then run `npm install` so it creates a new `package-lock.json` and is not installing from the old `package-lock.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `npm i xxxxxx` installs the peerDependencies along...